# Error with Namespace Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm experimenting with some Ruby code in a Ruby on Rails project and trying to code a nested namespace with inheritance.

In `app/messages/message.rb` I have the following code:

```
module Messages
   class Message
       def initialize
           puts "message constructor"
       end
   end
end
```

In `app/messages/emails/email.rb` I have this code:

```
module Emails
    class Email < Messages::Message
        def initialize
            super
            puts "email constructor"
        end
    end
end
```

From within a controller in my Rails application I attempt to instantiate a new `Email` like so:

```
message = Messages::Emails::Email.new
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Messages::Emails::Email, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/messengers/messages/emails/email.rb to define it):
```

I assume this is something I have done incorrectly with the namespaces. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails ignores the folder name just below `app`. So, create `app/messages/messages/message.rb` something like:

```
module Messages
  class Message
    def initialize
      puts "message constructor"
    end
  end
end
```

Then, `app/messages/emails/email.rb` should be:

```
module Emails
  class Email < Messages::Message
    def initialize
      super
      puts "email constructor"
    end
  end
end
```

Then you would do

```
Emails::Email.new
```

That file structure is a little unpretty, but it should do the trick.

Personally, I think I would create `app/messages/messages/message_base.rb`:

```
module Messages
  class MessageBase
    def initialize
      puts "message constructor"
    end
  end
end
```

And `app/messages/messages/email.rb`:

```
module Messages
  class Email < MessageBase
    def initialize
      super
      puts "email constructor"
    end
  end
end
```

But, I suppose it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: What do I need to do then if I need the `Message` class in its own namespace?

Comment: You'd need to do `app/messages/messages/emails/email` or include it manually with the regrettable `require`

Comment: With that folder structure, shouldn't I then be able to call `Messages::Emails::Email.new`? I'm getting this error with that configuration: `LoadError (Unable to autoload constant Messages::Emails::Email, expected /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/messages/messages/emails/email.rb to define it):` Instantiating `message = Emails::Email.new` still works however.

Comment: Like @jvillian said, Rails doesn't namespace first-level folders inside `app`

Comment: I guess maybe my invalid assumption (apart from the first-level folder being ignored) was that since Email inherited from Message that the namespace was nested and could be instantiated as `Messages::Emails::Email.new`. Is that correct?

Comment: @JoshBrody - using `Messages::Message` and `Emails::Email` (as in the first part) works fine for me with no `include`.

Comment: @CannonMoyer - If you're using the files/structures as in the first part of my answer, then you use `Emails::Email.new`, not `Messages::Emails::Email.new`.